# Best way to send larger File from android app to server

Tags: android, large-files

I am working on app which sends larger size file say 100mb max ed video,audio,files,
I am already using volley library for json post,I couldn't send larger size data using volley,more over volley doesn't supports multipart request.
I referered retrofit,picasso,okhttp etc for multipart support and large size data transfer but nothing worth to implement.
Anyone please tell me efficient way to send larger size data in android?
Is there any efficient networking libraries for doing the task ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: convert file into Base64 and send it on server

Comment: Check out loopj's library at http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: @KrunalShah sir thankyou for your response  I tried sending data by base64 it not working for large size data

Comment: @TimLilleSkuttBillström sir thankyou for your response i tried sending larger file it doesn't works for me in smith lib.if you came across any working code that send data larger than 50mb please say me

Comment: volley + mime-multipart will work .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382385/android-volley-posting-binary-body  or you can use diff httpclient and convert the file to byteArray , putting the array in byteArrayEntity and POST of the entity.

Comment: @RobertRowntree Sir thankyou for your response another one doubt for uploading large size file in byte array entity is possible or can we do streamed upload for uploading large size file ,ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076870/android-video-stream-upload-to-php-server